# How to create dynamic function takes table, two columns Name and return data concatenate together in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, string, concatenation

I'm new to SQL server and I want to make a function that's take table Name and name of two columns and return the data concatenate together.

If I have two columns called FirstName and LastName and each column have 50 row on it and for example row, one in FirstName have "Hello" and LastName have "World" I want the result to be like "Hello World"

I want function to be like that:

```
functionName(tableName, 1stCoulmnName, 2edColumnName)
```

I try to use table variable and `varchar` and still not working.

Comment: You would need to construct a dynamic SQL statement to build a query with desired table and column names. Dynamic SQL is not allowed in functions so you can't do what you ask in T-SQL. This is a task for the application code.

Answer (score 0):

We can use following example

1 - Generate a string with all column names - c1+c2+c3...

2 - Create a string with full SQL query, using 1 also.

3 - Execute string in 2 as dynamic SQL.

I'll combine 1 and 2 though.

```
declare @sql  varchar(max)
set @sql = 'SELECT ' 

declare @tbl varchar(100)
set @tbl = 'temp' -- put your table name here

SELECT @sql = @sql + COLUMN_NAME + '+'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @tbl 
-- AND TABLE_SCHEMA='junk'

set @sql = LEFT(@sql, LEN(@sql) - 1)
set @sql = @sql + ' FROM ' + @tbl

select @sql

-- dynamic SQL

exec(@sql)
```

Comment: Have you tried running this code from within a function as asked in the question?